# Generating sequence of Dates

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a code which gives me a sequence of dates in the form of     **"mmm yy"** format. e.g. **Jan 15** .

```
For i = 1 To 20
MsgBox Format(DateAdd("m", i, "01/01/2005"), "mmm") & " " & Right(Year(Date), 2)
Next i
```

The problem I am having is that when i goes on increasing the year does not change. So for example if **i** is **12** then it should be **Jan 06** but still it gives me **Jan 05** again. I want to generate a sequence from **Jan 05** to Today i.e. **Sep 15** Please advice.

Comment: What is the For i = 1 To 20 for? Just for debugging?

Comment: @MatthewD Yes, that's just to debug how can I go forward in months

Comment: The last part you are getting the year of today, which will always be 15.  Change the last part to `Format(DateAdd("m", i, "01/01/2005"), "yy")`

Comment: @ScottCraner that is incorrect.  `Right(Year(Date), 2)`  will begin returning `"16"` in just over three months, and will do so for 366 days, after which it will return `"17"` for the next 365 days, and so on.  (I know you know that but perhaps mentioning this will help others understand that it's not literally "today" as in 25 Sept 2015, but rather the date indicated by the system clock at run time.)

Comment: @phoog you are, of course, correct in your statement and I should have written it different.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable and add to that date.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim dDate As Date
    Dim i As Integer

    dDate = "01/01/2005"

    For i = 1 To 20
        MsgBox Format(dDate, "mmm") & " " & Right(Year(dDate), 2)
        dDate = DateAdd("m", 1, dDate)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Sub oiudskfh()
   For i = 1 To 20
      Dim d As Date
      d = DateAdd("m", i, "01/01/2015")
      MsgBox Format(d, "mmm") & " " & Right(d, 2)
   Next i
End Sub
```